# Authorization in SignalR 2.0

Tags: asp.net, authorization, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a Web server with forms authentication and another server that hosts the SignalR Hubs. Using the forms authentication cookie I want to extract the current user using the code below. This would be possible using a HttpModule, but when using SignalR a HttpModule cannot be used.

Is there any other way to archive what I want to do?

```
public class AuthorizationHubModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    public AuthorizationHubModule()
    {
    }

    protected override bool OnBeforeConnect(IHub hub)
    {
        var cookies = hub.Context.Request.Cookies;
        if (cookies.ContainsKey(".ASPXAUTH") == true)
        {
            // Get the user, populate the Thread.CurrentUser...
            Cookie cookie = cookies[".ASPXAUTH"];

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

                GenericIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
                GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]);

                // Cannot do this because User is readonly (this is possible in a normal HttpModule)
                //hub.Context.User = principal;
            }
        }

        return base.OnBeforeConnect(hub);
    }
}
```

The thing we are after, is to set the IPrincipal associated with SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you are trying to extract user info of the logged in user from context. If that is correct this can be simply achieved by doing the following:

1. Add [Authorize] attribute to your hub class.
2. Then use Context.User.Identity to get user identity.

Since you are using persistent connection the authorization process would need to be taken care by you. Refer [this link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/persistent-connection-authorization) and you can tweak the code provided there as per your need.

To change the identity of the request you must add FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate to your global.asax. Here is a sample code that I wrote for my application:

```
protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;

                    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                    e.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                      new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), _user.GetUserRoles(username));                        
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //somehting went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And without that attribute? The attribute does not work on PersistentConnection :(

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately IRequest.User is readonly, so there is no actual way of changing the IPrincipal. I mean, the problem is that we need to change the IPrincipal in SignalR, that is what the question is about. Cheers.

Comment: You mentioned you have two servers, how do you connect to your signalr hub from your other server. It would be good if you can paste the code.

Comment: The MVC app holds a duplex TCP connection to the server. That connection relays all the information from the server to the SignalR connections. This is not related with the question :P

Comment: I suspect in your case the problem lies in how the information reaches the SignalR hub. Can you post the code for your persistent connection class.

Comment: I am not using any hub, I only use the PersistentConnection.

Comment: Right so can you post the code for your class that inherits from PersistentConnection class.

Comment: I cannot paste the code in a comment. There is nowhere in the PersistentConnection class to set the IPrincipal though.

Comment: In the link I shared you get an IRequest object that has Identity. You can use that to get Iprincipal object as already being done in the code.

Comment: I am not sure if I truly understand why you want to set Iprincipal object in the first place. Can you be specific on what you are trying to achieve. Iprincipal is something I believe you cannot set due to security issues. Rather you will have to code the complete process if that is exactly what you need. Here is a sample code: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV

Comment: Custom authentication, I want to set the IPrincipal to my custom IPrincpial. It is a common practice. Thread.CurrentPrincipal, HttpContext.Current.User and HttpContextBase.User are writable, but IRequest.User is readonly. That is the problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the clarification you provided. Hope this addresses your problem.

Comment: @vtortola please mark the response as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Signal-R cannot modify the associated IPrincipal because SignalR is not conceived to do authentication, but it gets the authentication context from the application. So the right way of doing this, as @Shashank has pointed out, is to use Forms or whatever you use in your application, and SignalR will get this context from it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the interface `IUserIdProvider` and add it using

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.Resolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => provider.Object);
```

You can read more [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

Comment: That interface only defines how do you get a UserId from the IRequest, but does not provide a way of setting an IPrincipal anywhere.