# How to set Authorization Header in ng2-signalr?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2, signalr

I am using library `ng2-signalr`in ionic 2. Issue is that i don't know how to set authorization header. I have search but didn't find any example.

My code for connecting to server hub.

```
   let options: IConnectionOptions = { qs:{userId:1}, url: "http://192.168.0.211:44337"};

        console.log("Stage 1");
            //Header for 'this.singalR.connect'
        this.signalR.connect(options)
            .then((connection) => {                      

                console.log("Client Id: " + connection.id);                     
             }, (err) => {
                console.log("SignalR Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
```

How to set below header ?

```
  var headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + accessToken  //accessToken contain bearer value.
        });
```

Library: [ng2-signalr](https://github.com/HNeukermans/ng2-signalr)

**Update 1**

Here on link [Query String Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069815/4154016). A workaround is mention to pass `authorization token` in `qs` and handle accordingly. But i want to set in header so this solution does not suit me . One more reason as i have one another client(Simple angularjs signalr) which is working fine when i set header just like below.

```
 $.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = { Authorization: //here set header};
```

**Note: Before implementing Authorization same code working fine as i don't need to set authorization header.**

Comment: did you try setting token in qs?

Comment: @suraj no not yet .oky i'm trying but that does not make a sense to set header values in query string `qs` .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196266/signalr-authentication-with-javascript-client

Comment: @suraj given link is work around to pass token in query string and handle on server side accordingly. Right now it does not suit me because for that i need to change my server side code. if i change my server side then i have to change one more client(simple angularjs Signalr) which is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently (v2.0.4) not implemented in ng2-signalr. 
As a workaround,  you can try:

```
declare var $: any;
$.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + accessToken  //accessToken contain bearer value.
});
```